# Is it possible to add \hspace before \begin{lstlisting}?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, lstlisting

Hello I would like to add some `hspace` before a `\begin{lstlisting}` part so that my code will be tabed to the right. this is not working:

```
\hspace{4mm}\begin{lstlisting}
dateRangeInput("daterange", "Select Date", start = min(OLS.Data$Date), 
end = max(OLS.Data$Date))
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: See the `listings` manual, it has features to set the margins of a listing.

Comment: @daleif okay I will have a look. Another question: How can I use comma in \hspace? for example \hspace{4.8mm} is not working, why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please don't ask new unrelated questions, post another. `\hspace{4.8mm}` (using a dot, not comma) works just fine, but it ignored if used first on a line.

Comment: @dalif: `\hspace*` doesn't work either: `lstlistings` starts on a new line.

Comment: @Bernard doesn't `lstlisting` start a new paragraph, so of course it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

Either the  key `xleftmargin=`. You also have to change the caption margin via `\captionsetup{margin=}` from `caption`,
or nesting the `\stlistings`environment in an `adjustwidth` environment (from `changepage`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage{changepage} 
 \lstset{language=C}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{singlelinecheck = off, format = plain}

 \begin{document}

\section{A first section}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. 

{\captionsetup[lstlisting]{margin = 4.8mm}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption ={My caption}, label = lst1, xleftmargin=4.8mm]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write('Case insensitive ');
Write('Pascal keywords.');
\end{lstlisting} 
}

\begin{adjustwidth}{4.8mm}{}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption ={My caption}, label = lst1]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write('Case insensitive ');
Write('Pascal keywords.');
\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustwidth}

 \end{document}
```

[image]